# how to parse field values from controller to java script?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi i am trying to get to display all account records using @Remoteaction Annotation.. Records Displaying in my Page but name field only displaying remaing fields and all displaying undefined how to parse filed values from controller to java script

Mentioned here my Apex Controller, java script and result screenshot

Apex Controller:

```
@remoteaction
public static list<account> getAccount(string searchtext){
  string query;
  query = 'select id,name,createddate,Industry,accountnumber,active__C from account order by '+searchtext+' ASC ' ;
  return database.query(query);
}
}
```

Javscript:

```
var accstring = document.getElementById("list1").innerHTML;
toggle.getAccount(accstring,
function(result,event){
           var html = '<table>';
           html = html + '<tr><td><b>Name :</b></td>';
           html = html + '<td><b>Industery:</b></td></tr>';
           if(event.status){
             debugger;
           for (var prop in event.result) { 
           html = html + '<tr><td>'+event.result[prop].Name+'</td> <td>'+event.result[prop].Industry+'</td></tr>';
           }
            html = html + '</table>';
            $("#opportunityDetails").html(html);
            x.style.visibility = "hidden";
           }
           else {
             alert(event.message);
      }
},{escape:true});
  }
```

Result::

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the Apex @Remoteaction method too in your question.

Comment: Hi Thank You for Responding Added My apex Controller also could you please check once above code

Comment: You have an injection vulnerability in your code...do you actually have read permission on that field?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply Not only industry filed except name all fields getting undefined all fields have read permission

Comment: Usually I return wrapper list as sometimes the field API names are case sensitive. Maybe you could try that.